# Export not working for large number of data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm using 
window.location.href = "some ajax call";
for exporting, but when there is large number of data (for eg.5000),I'm getting the result as "**Request-URI Too Large "pathname"
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.**"

Can someone please provide me the solution for this problem?

Comment: First of all `window.location.href` is used to redirect the browser; how is this related to "some ajax call"? Second, the error means that you are trying to do GET with the data in the query string. Query string has a limit. You should use POST instead. And finally - what does your question have to do with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Because url has its [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), url length can not be exceeds 2,000 characters.

You should use `POST` request instead of `GET` and send data inside body.

**CODE**

```
    $http({
        type: 'POST',
        url: exportUrl, //this should not contain data
        data: "data=" + escape(JSON.stringify(exprotData)),
        success: function (data) {
            //success code
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //error code
        }
    });
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.